# Как перебрать данные в python?

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Как можно перебрать данные в питоне?
У меня есть данные, которые я скачиваю с google spreadsheet в формате output csv.
Как можно перебрать эти данные, чтобы каждое предложение пронумеровывать.
Пробывал использовать цикл while, но почему то не получается. Какие есть способы решить этот вопрос?

```
from cookielib import CookieJar
from urllib2 import build_opener, HTTPCookieProcessor
opener = build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor(CookieJar()))
print("\n")
resp = opener.open('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?
  key=11WR6rwQhL4wUDN8I77ju_5rzZl8IglsUjtUDI6pZsAQ&output=csv')
data = resp.read()
print(data)
```

И спец символ тут - "\n"

Comment: `import csv` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы не заморачиваться с файлом, можно поместить данные в буфер:

```
import csv
import StringIO

import requests

rs = requests.get(url)
buffer_str = StringIO.StringIO(rs.content.decode('utf-8'))

reader = csv.reader(buffer_str)
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Консоль:

```
...
['UA.003.02643-17', '07.04.2017', 'ОС ДП НДІ "Система"', 'VOLKSWAGEN TOURAN', 'M1', '', '2012', 'WVGZZZ1TZDW038385', 'б/к', 'Євро-5', '', 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxkRJD85jfUZMDBBbEJNX0diUms', '']
['UA.003.02644-17', '07.04.2017', 'ОС ДП НДІ "Система"', 'SKODA OCTAVIA', 'M1', '', '2011', 'TMBCT61Z2C2030646', 'б/к', 'Євро-5', '', 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxkRJD85jfUZUWRlM1V3UTdlTkU', '']
['UA.003.02645-17', '07.04.2017', 'ОС ДП НДІ "Система"', 'MERCEDES-BENZ CITAN', 'N1', '', '2013', 'WDF4156051U111452', 'б/к', 'Євро-5', '', 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxkRJD85jfUZU3Y1YUR0a18tUlU', '']
...
```

Comment: А вот если мне нужно данные с гугл таблицы, я так же само могу переставить урл и все?

Comment: У меня не то, я получаю ошибку "<<TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function>>"

Comment: @DanTheMan по идеи, да, скорее всего формат csv там такой же (есть несколько форматов). Да виноват, незнал что в питоне 2 нет такого параметра и придется гемороиться, поэтому если второй вариант с StringIo работает, давайте я его и оставлю, все-равно первый костыльный из-за сохранения и считывания в файл